# Problem with scanf loading struct -> char[]

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, scanf

I'm dealing with this issue:
I've been creating linked list (using a structure) and I want to load input from user.
When I debug this code, the debugger stop on the line of scanf.

```
typedef struct Person{
char name[64];
int number;
} Person;

Person* record = malloc(sizeof(Person));
printf("Input name: \n");
scanf("%63s", record->name);
```

I know that (*record).number == record->number and '&' is used to get an adress of variable but I have no idea how to solve my problem in the simplest way if I want to use scanf for loading input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work without the debugger?

Comment: Seems to work..according to me.

Comment: It is not just that the debugger is awaiting your input?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse in Windows 7 and when I run the program, it is running and never stop. Printf doesn't print anything (because there must be error in code).

Comment: There's nothing wrong AFAICT with the snippet you've posted; the issue must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @John Bode: as wrote below, there must be some unexpected behaviour of Eclipse environment because other code is right.

Answer (score 1):

When a program is debugged using gdb and a scanf statement is encountered, the debugger will prompt for user input. If you give the input at that point and hit Enter, the execution will continue.

For eg., 
1. If the source code is the following in a file name 'llist.c'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person{
char name[64];
int number;
} Person;

int main()
{

    Person* record = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if(record == NULL)
    {
       printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
       return;
    }
    printf("Input name: \n");
    scanf("%63s", record->name);
    printf("Name %s\n", record -> name);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it using the debug option as

> gcc -g -o list llist.c

1. Run the debugger as `gdb ./list` and enter the command `run` to start the program execution.
2. When prompted for input, enter any string and hit Enter.
3. The string is then printed to the terminal.

Comment: Hi, this works but when I try to run or debug the same program in Eclipse, it doesn't work! The same issue. So I think there must be something wrong between Eclipse and Win..